# How do I use two different websocket url based on context in react-apollo?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client, graphql-subscriptions

I have got a problem.

The scenario is we have two **graphql** servers.

I have split them passing context in the query/mutation options.

It works but I also have two different **websocket** setup.

As we can split subscription using **hasSubscription(operation.query)**. It can be split only depending on query type.

But as I mentioned I have two **websockets** and I see there is no option to pass context in **useSubscription** like **useQuery/useMutation**.

Here is the documentation: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/subscriptions/#subscribetomore

There is no option to pass context in the **subscription**.

So what's the right way to achieve this?

**Note**: I'm using reactjs here.

Answer (score 0):

try using `useSubscription` hook with `client` option. Thank you.

https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/subscriptions/#useSubscription